# Test process not terminated when restarting it from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In the middle of a c++ debugging session I press restart [image: restart] in visual studio.

For some reason this starts a new test process but doesn't terminate the old one. So filelocks aren't released and the new process fails due to this.

How can I make visual studio terminate the old process first?

Clarification: I restart the debugging process by using the button: [image: restart] I don't restart visual studio.

Comment: try to close all instances of visual studio, if not works, restart your OS, it will definately release the lock

Comment: Yes, but repeating the process repeats the problem so that not a solution

Comment: When we close intance of visual studio, many background process are running, to avoid that error wait for these process to end, and also report a problem on official visual studio website so they fix that, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I'm not restarting visual studio, just the debugging. Added clarification

Comment: I would avoid restarting the application while debugging and report the bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Did you try disabling your anti-virus?